# MySQL: In what order do subqueries get executed?

Tags: mysql, subquery

I'm having a problem in which my code executes properly, but only spits out an "OK", instead of an actual query. I'll reproduce it below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `Iteration` (Trait VarChar(64))
BEGIN


SET @sql = CONCAT("SELECT Quarter_Year,
IF((SELECT Index_Number FROM TemporaryTable WHERE Stock = 'AAA ' ) = 1, (SELECT ",Trait," FROM Applications.Table WHERE Stock = 'AAA'), NULL) AS AAA,
IF((SELECT Index_Number FROM TemporaryTable WHERE Stock = 'BBB' ) = 2, (SELECT ",Trait," FROM Applications.Table WHERE Stock = 'BBB'), NULL) AS BBB,
IF((SELECT Index_Number FROM TemporaryTable WHERE Stock = 'CCC' ) = 3, (SELECT ",Trait," FROM Applications.Table WHERE Stock = 'CCC'), NULL) AS CCC,
FROM Applications.Table  
GROUP BY Quarter_Year");
PREPARE Statement FROM @sql;
EXECUTE Statement;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE Statement;
END
```

The above is a procedure which I've created. It references a `TemporaryTable`which is executed below, along with a call to the procedure. Additionally, I've made sure that the "IF" statements in the procedure always evaluate to `TRUE`. I had to structure the above in such a confusing way because it was the only way to embed `WHERE` statements that could affect each line of the call.

```
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS TemporaryTable;
CREATE Table TemporaryTable
(SELECT DISTINCT Index_Number AS Index_Number,
Stock AS Stock
FROM Applications.Table);

CALL Iteration('Trait1');
```

My operating theory right now is that the `SELECT` call in the `TRUE` part of each line is being executed properly, as I had read somewhere that subqueries like it are evaluated before general queries.

However, I'm not certain why, if the above is all correct, the results are only an "OK" instead of a table.

Any help is deeply appreciated.

**UPDATE**

I've gone ahead and taken some advice, and tried to execute the below, taking it out of a prepared statement:

```
SELECT Quarter_Year,
IF((SELECT Index_Number FROM TemporaryTable WHERE Stock = 'AAA ' ) = 1, (SELECT Trait1 FROM Applications.Table WHERE Stock = 'AAA'), NULL) AS AAA,
IF((SELECT Index_Number FROM TemporaryTable WHERE Stock = 'BBB' ) = 2, (SELECT Trait1 FROM Applications.Table  WHERE Stock = 'BBB'), NULL) AS BBB,
IF((SELECT Index_Number FROM TemporaryTable WHERE Stock = 'CCC' ) = 3, (SELECT Trait1 FROM Applications.Table  WHERE Stock = 'CCC'), NULL) AS CCC
    FROM Applications.Table   
GROUP BY Quarter_Year;
```

Unfortunately, it still has the same issue-- it only spits back out an "OK" instead of any actual results.
**2nd UPDATE**

I've also experimented with the following code:

```
SELECT Quarter_Year,
(SELECT Trait1 FROM Applications.Table WHERE Stock = 'AAA')  AS AAA,
(SELECT Trait1 FROM Applications.Table  WHERE Stock = 'BBB') AS BBB,
(SELECT Trait1 FROM Applications.Table  WHERE Stock = 'CCC') AS CCC
    FROM Applications.Table   
GROUP BY Quarter_Year;
```

It returns the same-- "OK".

I'm wondering what precisely makes a query return an `OK`.

**3rd Update**

Applications.Table is set up like this for columns:

1. Index_Number
2. Quarter_Year
3. And a series of Traits, including Trait1, Trait2, Trait3, etc, as column heads.

For Index_Number, it goes 1,2,3,4,5,etc

Quarter_Year is 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, etc.

Traits are all between 0 and 2, all of which have decimals.

Stock Numbers are just letter codes.

So, for example:

```
Index Number  Stock  Quarter_Year    Trait1    Trait2    Trait3
1              AAA   2009           1.1       0.3        0.5
2              BBB   2010           1.6       1.2        2.0
3              CCC   2011           1.3       1.1        0.7
4              DDD   2012           0.9       0.5        0.4
5              EEE   2013           0.2       1.9        0.1
```

Comment: Is it mysql or sql-server? You tagged both.
If it's mysql I see no reason to put that into a prepared statement, just do the query in the procedure. Also, I have a hard time understanding what you are trying to do. Could you add the tablel DDL and some data along with what you expect as outpu.

Comment: My bad. It's only mysql. I'm using a prepared statement since "Trait1" within the call is going to be a number of different variables. While I understand the above might be confusing, I'm fairly certain that it's the best option, given the subsequent reuse and other, unrelated steps that I'm going to have to embark on.

Comment: What do you mean by "table DLL"? I can't really add the data, unfortunately. I would think what data I'm trying to pass isn't really relevant either, given what results I'm already receiving. The fact that it executes, but returns an "OK" doesn't depend on what data is being passed.

Comment: I've updated the original post, per your recommendation, @AndreasWederbrand

Comment: I was asking for the table layout of Applications.Table (thats the DDL) and som example rows.

Comment: Sure. I'll update the original post with some sample rows .

Comment: Your queries doesn't match the ddl you posted. Do "show create table Application.Table" and post that. It will help people help you if you add correct information to your questions.

Comment: I've gone ahead and added an additional column, which should make it complete. If it isn't, can you kindly explain what you mean by the queries not matching?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96443/discussion-between-andreas-wederbrand-and-z-r).